# Multiple Sitemaps Doesn't Index Quickly - How To Get Quick Index

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, google-index, xml-sitemap

I have a serious problem in my site: http://www.coimbatorematrimony.com

I will create multiple `sitemaps.xml` with all terms & conditions of Google Webmaster and some other search engines. I have 37 sitemaps each average 25.000 links, but totally index that 15.000 links only.

My sitemap link is http://www.coimbatorematrimony.com/sitemap_index.xml

Comment: I have a very similar issue on one of my sites with many large sitemaps like this so I am curious to see the answers, but I have a feeling it has to do with Google pushing sites like this to the back of the queue in favor of smaller sites, especially if your sites pages are similar in content to each other.

Comment: This has been asked a hundred times over, Google does not scan all pages on one visit, it can take months to complete and depends on how important Google believes your site is.... Sitemaps help but it doesn't mean it will scan any more than it wants too. Build backlinks, and work on getting more traffic and Google in Good time will look after the rest.

Comment: Yes, Similar problem here, I did submitted my XML site map. It usually takes 2 to 3 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your sitemaps in your [robots.txt](http://yourcurrencyconverters-tostaky.rhcloud.com/robots.txt), one line per `sitemap.xml`. Google will pick them faster, but there is no guarantee it will process them fully. You do not have control on this. It is more probable Google will process them little by little. If all your pages are too similar, Google will not index them all.

Google does not revisit the sitemaps you submit to Webmaster Tools, but it revisits `robots.txt` frequently. So, it will reprocess your sitemaps more frequently too. Something important is to refresh your pages' `lastmod` tag when these are modified. If you don't cheat with these tags, Google responds to them pretty well.

**More**

Use the `priority` tag to tell Google which pages it should focus on first. If you have 25 000 pages, Google may not be willing to process all pages. It will pick those with high priority first.

For more info, see personal blog [post](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/2013/03/sitemapxml-battlefield-dos-donts.html).

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it, thanks!